# MVC Ensure User Travers Endpoints in Order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Say I have three endpoints

```
First/foo/bar
Second/fizz/buzz
Third/whatever
```

Only one of these endpoints is valid at a time, starting with first, then second, and so on.  This is a problem is the user tries to go back, or they pick one of these endpoints from their history -- they'll be presented with an error dialog.

I thought I could use SessionState to keep track of the most recently accessed (and thus valid) endpoint and redirect with action filters based on that information, but my team has disabled SessionState.

So does MVC have a canonical way to ensure a user navigates certain endpoints in order?

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't provide any behavior over what a browser does. That is, it is using the HTTP protocol and there is no way to prevent a user from manually typing in a URL in their browser (unless you have written your own browser that does this).

However, you could design your application as a single page that uses a JavaScript framework (such as JQuery or AngularJS) so the browser doesn't actually change URLs. This would prevent the browser from tracking the interaction between the JavaScript code and the server. Then you can guarantee that the user can only view the "pages" in the correct order.